# Print output with color style in GDB python script?

Tags: gdb-python

I'd like to call `print('somestr')` in a python script called in GDB (`(gdb) source my_script.py`),  and style the output in console colors. I tried the python [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) package which works in terminal, but not when invoking from GDB. Is there a way to print in colors in GDB python script? Haven't got any clue from the Python API below.

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html

Comment: Have you tried it with the [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)? Like `print("normal \x1b[31;1mred\x1b[m normal")`.

Comment: @ssbssa thanks for reminding on that. Seems print the ANSI escape codes works in python script even it is invoked from GDB.